# structure name not declared and swap function swaps without pass by refrence

Tags: c++, struct, structure, swap

I have this code,which takes input of 3 students from division a and b each.
those 2 divions are sorted and merged in a 3rd array according to birth dates of students.
the swap function ,I have not passed anything by refrence still its swapping and sort output is correct !!!.

NOTE:the line below #include..

```
void swap(struct a,struct b)
```

it should be

```
void swap(struct student a,struct student b)
```

but without changing that the program is runnong and giving correct outputs !! how ??

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

void swap(struct a,struct b);
void findweek(struct student ar[10],int l,int bd1,int bm1);
struct student
{
    //m is for month and b is for birthdate prn=prn number,name=name of student
    int m,bd;
    char prn[10],name[10];
};

int main()
{
    //2 divisions a and b declared and will be merged into c
    struct student a[3], b[3], c[6];

    //division a input 
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        cout<<" Enter name of student "<<endl;
        cin>>a[i].name;
        cout<<"Enter prn no. "<<endl;
        cin>>a[i].prn;
        cout<<"Enter birth day "<<endl;
        cin>>a[i].bd;
        cout<<"Enter birth month "<<endl;
        cin>>a[i].m;
    }

    //sorting of a 
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<3;j++)
        {
            if(a[i].m>a[j].m)
            {
                swap(a[i],a[j]);
            }
            else if(a[i].m==a[j].m)
            {
                if(a[i].bd>a[j].bd)
                {
                    swap(a[i],a[j]);
                }
            }

        }
    }


    //division b input 
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        cout<<" Enter name of student "<<endl;
        cin>>b[i].name;
        cout<<"Enter prn no. "<<endl;
        cin>>b[i].prn;
        cout<<"Enter birth day "<<endl;
        cin>>b[i].bd;
        cout<<"Enter birth month "<<endl;
        cin>>b[i].m;
    }


    //sorting of b 
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<3;j++)
        {
            if(b[i].m>b[j].m)
            {
                swap(b[i],b[j]);
            }
            else if(b[i].m==b[j].m)
            {
                if(b[i].bd>b[j].bd)
                {
                    swap(b[i],b[j]);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    cout<<"-----------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"Division A"<<endl;
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {       //c has merged array , a being filled first
        c[i]=a[i];
        count++;
        cout <<c[i].name<<"\t"<<c[i].prn<<"\t"<<c[i].bd<<"|"<<c[i].m<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"Division B"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        //resume filling the array from count
        c[count]=b[i];
        cout <<c[count].name<<"\t"<<c[count].prn<<"\t"<<c[count].bd<<"|"<<c[count].m<<endl;
        count++;
    }

    int bd1,bm1;
    cout<<"Enter date to find birthdays in that week "<<endl;
    cin>>bd1;
    cout<<"Enter corresponding month "<<endl;
    cin>>bm1;
    findweek(c,count,bd1,bm1);
    return 0;
}
//to swap the structure student arrays for sorting
void swap(struct student a,struct student b)
{
    struct student t;
    t=a;
    a=b;
    b=t;
}


void findweek(struct student ar[10],int l,int bd1,int bm1)
{
    int count=0;

    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {

        int month_end=30;
        int next_month=bm1+1;
        //if(bd1>=23)
        int end_date=bd1+7-month_end;
    //  else 
        int endofweek=bd1+7;
        //l is length of ar , ar=copy of merged array, bd1&bm1 are date and month to search for birthday in that week
        if((ar[i].m==bm1&&ar[i].bd>=bd1&&ar[i].bd<=endofweek)||ar[i].m==bm1+1&&ar[i].bd<=end_date)
        {
            if(month_end-bd1>7)
                cout <<ar[i].name<<"\t"<<ar[i].prn<<"\t"<<ar[i].bd<<"|"<<ar[i].m<<endl;
            else
            {

                if((ar[i].m==bm1&&ar[i].bd>=bd1)||(ar[i].m==next_month&&ar[i].bd<=end_date))
                {
                    cout <<ar[i].name<<"\t"<<ar[i].prn<<"\t"<<ar[i].bd<<"|"<<ar[i].m<<endl;
                }

            }

            count++;
            if(count>7)
                break;  
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It compiles even if you remove this line:

```
void swap(struct a,struct b);
```

Also, it compiles if you remove the whole `swap` function.
How is it?

Quite simple.

You are defining a function that takes two arguments: an incomplete type `struct a` and an incomplete type `struct b`.
That function is simply discarded from the overload set while searching the one to be used at function call.
Your `main` is not using your `swap` function. Instead, it's using the one from `std::` namespace.
It is probably introduced by `iostream` or `string`, it's implementation defined.

Try changing the name of the function or putting a `throw` in your implementation of `swap`. In the second case, your runtime won't be affected.

Minimal, (not-)working example to reproduce the issue:

```
void f(struct s);
struct S {};
int main() { f(S{}); }
void f(S) {}
```

As you can see, the error is that you are referring to an incomplete type `struct s`.

`swap` is kinda of a somehow misleading example that compiles for the reasons above.
Reproducing an issue with a minimal example is often helpful.